# Adding a sequence to a large Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have queries that take an existing large table and build tables off of them for reporting.  The problem is that the source tables are 60-80MM+ records and it takes a long time to recreate.  I'd like to be able to identify which records are new so I can build just add the new records to the reporting tables.

To me, the best way to identify this is to have an identity column.  Is there any significant cost to creating this and adding it to the table?

Separately, is it possible to create a materialized view that takes data from one of these tables but add a sequence as part of the materialized view?  That is, something like

```
create materialized view some_materialized_view as
select somesequence.nextval, source_table.*
from source_table?
```

Comment: Why a sequence rather than a date field initialized with a DEFAULT. Sequences aren't necessarily sequential (multi-instance RAC or simply not visible transactionally) so you need to allow a bit of slack to avoid missing anything.

Comment: We do you need to back date the data? Just add a new column with default of sequence.nextval (or if you are on an older version, perhaps systimestamp). Initial population is just : *where seq is null or seq > ..." and subsequent population just "where seq > ..."

Comment: I was think of a sequence not so much to get things in an order but merely to identify the records that are new to the source table.  There already is a date field, but I'm concerned that it would not be fine grained enough to clearly identify the new from the old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a sequence based column to your table, but as Gary suggests I wouldn't do that.

The task you are about to solve is so common that other solutions have been already implemented.

The first built-in option that comes to mind is the system change number SCN, a kind of Oracle internal clock. By default, tables are set up to record the SCN of the whole (usually 8K) block, containing usually many rows, but you can set a table to keep a record of the SCN that changed every row. Then you can track the columns that are new or change and have not been copied to your reporting tables.

```
CREATE TABLE t (c1 NUMBER) ROWDEPENDENCIES;
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
COMMIT;
SELECT c1, ora_rowscn FROM t;
```

Secondly, I would think of adding a date column. With 60-80 mio rows I wouldn't do this with `ALTER TABLE xxx ADD (d DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE)`, but with rename, create as select, drop:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM all_objects;
RENAME t TO told;
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT sysdate AS d, told.* FROM told;
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY d DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE;
DROP TABLE told;
```

Thirdly, I would read up on [materialized views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/partitions-views-and-other-schema-objects.html#GUID-29E19A46-D91F-4EEB-BD0C-E65A89F2F59B). I never had the chance to use this a work, but in theory, you should be able to set up a materialized view log on your 80 m table that records changes and updates dependent materialized views.

And forthly, I'd look into partitioning your large table on the (newly introduced) date column, so that identifying the new rows will become faster. That sadly depends on your version and Oracle license, though.